# Symfony swiftmailer in production environment

Tags: php, email, symfony, production-environment, swiftmailer

I have a problem for sending mails with Swiftmailer in Symfony2.
Let me explain it: when I go to my website with the app_dev.php, I could send messages, there is no problem (also, when I write `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);` in app.php).

So, I don't understand why this works in dev and not in prod.

Here is my configuration files:

parameters.yml:

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: ****.ovh.net
mailer_username: postmaster@mywebsite.com
mailer_password: ****
mailer_port: ****
```

config.yml:

```
swiftmailer:
transport: "%mailer_transport%"
host:      "%mailer_host%"
username:  "%mailer_username%"
password:  "%mailer_password%"
port:      "%mailer_port%"
spool:     { type: memory }
```

And this is the php code, but I think there is no problem with it because as I said there is no problem in dev mode.

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance() -> setSubject('Test')
         -> setFrom('postmaster@mywebsite.com')
         -> setTo($user -> getMail())
         -> setBody('Test');
$this -> get('mailer') -> send($message);
```

Thank you very much if you know where is the problem.

Comment: can you look at your prod.log and see if there are any errors?  I read over your question and am a little confused.  You wrote "So, I don't understand why this works in prod and not in dev."  The title said it did not work in prod.

Comment: I'm sorry this was a mistake, I wanted to say "I don't understand why it works in dev and not in prod".

So, this is the log when I try to send a mail:

`[2015-03-29 11:22:44] app.ERROR: Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host smtp.mywebsite.com [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known #0] [] []`

It say, that it couldn't connect to the smtp but in dev, it could, this is strange...

Comment: I suggest manually deleting the prod cache directory and re-installing and dumping assets again.

Comment: It works! Thank you very very much! I think that I forgot to empty the prod cache, so symfony did not know my new configuration for swiftmailer.
Now, I'm feeling stupid ^^.
Thank you :)

Comment: since that worked, can you check the answer I added.  You are not the only one this happens to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something worked in dev, but not prod try manually deleting the prod cache directory and re-installing and dumping assets again.  Review this [checklist](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html) from the docs.